# Javascript Histogram

Tags: javascript, histogram

I am trying to create a histogram of the number of characters in a string using javascript. Right now I have got the string to show the frequency of characters, but i am trying to display it like so..

EG for the string Hello : 
a:0
b:0
c:0
d:0
e:1
f:0 
...

This is my code.

```
class myString {



  constructor(text) {
    this.text = text.toLowerCase();
    this.text = this.text.replace(/\s/g, '');
  }


  getFrequency() {

    let string = this.text
    var letters = {};
    for (var i=0; i<string.length;i++) {
        var character = string.charAt(i);
        if (letters[character]) {
           letters[character]++;
        } else {
           letters[character] = 1;
        }
    }
    return letters;
};

    Histogram(){

        var stringBase = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];

        var letters = this.getFrequency();

        console.log(letters);

    }


}
```

I want my code to print to the console like so.

[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDP2T.png)

Comment: What's the problem? What exactly do you mean by "display"?

Comment: printing it to the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate the `stringBase` with [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and take the counts from `letters`. If a count doesn't exist for a letter use 0 instead. Flatten the array of objects to a single object using [Array#assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [array spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```js
class myString {
  constructor(text) {
    this.text = text.toLowerCase();
    this.text = this.text.replace(/\s/g, '');
  }
  
  getFrequency() {
    const string = this.text;
    const letters = {};
    for(let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
      const character = string.charAt(i);
      if (letters[character]) {
        letters[character]++;
      } else {
        letters[character] = 1;
      }
    }
    return letters;
  };

  Histogram() {
    const stringBase = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

    const letters = this.getFrequency();

    return Object.assign({}, ...stringBase.map((l) => ({
      [l]: '*'.repeat(letters[l] || 0)
    })));
    
    /** to display in the console directly
    console.log(Object.assign({}, ...stringBase.map((l) => ({
      [l]: '*'.repeat(letters[l] || 0)
    }))));
    **/
  }
}

const str = new myString('hello');

console.log(str.Histogram());
```

Comment: I am adding this code in and its not printing to the console

Comment: @GurdevSingh - it returns a string, which I show in the console. I'll add a comment of what you need to change to console it directly.

Comment: but i need it to be used with the console.log in the histogram function

Comment: I know. I've added a comment with the code you need to console it inside the histogram.

Comment: So what variable is the number, as i need to change the number to that number of astrix *

Comment: `etters[l] || 0` is the number.

Comment: I've added the asterisks as well.

Comment: than you it works perfect, but i dont understand whats actually going on, could you explain?

Comment: It creates a series of object with a single property - the letter, with a count value, or number of asterisks. Then it merges them to a single object by spreading into Object#assign.